# What is the correct setting to replicate all indices across all nodes in Elasticsearch 5.6?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, elasticsearch-5

Cannot upgrade at the moment and I am stuck with Elasticsearch 5.6.

Trying to get cluster-mode working on GKE with success, but one major problem. Whenever I do a rolling restart (`StatefulSet`) of the Elasticsearch cluster I can get the cluster into a red state from which it cannot recover. Doesn't happen all the time though and works flawlessly if I only kill one node (out of three).

For some reason the restarted node is not able to recover their primary/replica shards on startup. Or the next node is terminated to early before shard allocation has been finished?

In any way I was looking for an option where I just keep every index fully on every node (mix of primary and replica shards). Not sure how to configure this properly.

How do I configure a Elasticsearch cluster with **three** nodes and two indices to survive an outage of **two** nodes?

EDIT: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/delayed-allocation.html is probably what I need, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

A [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) is a way to create stateful components within a distributed systems. Thus, Pods are intended execute independently with its own state. In fact a StatefulSet have a unique ordinal index, a stable network identity, and if stops it's data are not visible from the running nodes.
Here the block diagram to access the PV/PVC:

```
 PV - PVC - POD1 \
 PV - PVC - POD2 - StatefulSet  
 PV - PVC - POD3 /
```

What you cannot reach with StatefulSet (differently than Deployment) is to access the POD's data if that POD stops. This means that if you have 3 PODs: if 1 POD stops your application may continue to work, if 2 PODs stops your application likely doesn't work.

If you need to continue to access the data if some PODs stop, you probably need a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), instead, where every pod access the same data on PV-PVC:

```
          / POD1 \
 PV - PVC - POD2 - Deployment
          \ POD3 /
```

So, in order to meet your requirements, try to use Deployments instead of StatefulSets.

Then you can distribute PODs on each node, following [the official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/), in order to enable application availability in case 2 out of 3 nodes will not be reachable.
To do that you can use the following yaml example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
template:
  spec:
    topologySpreadConstraints:
      - maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
        labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: foo
        matchLabelKeys:
          - pod-template-hash
```

Comment: Hey Alez, thanks for the response, but in fact I do want to split to different PVCs.

Comment: I edited my answer to also exaplain how to distribute pods among nodes.

Regarding PVC, you can split to multiple different PVC with both StatefulSet and Deployment. The differences between the two ways is how they access data and how they provide availability. If a StatefulSet pod crashs you loose all its data unless it restarts. This means that if 2 pods out of 3 are not reachable your application stops. Deployments are more flexible and your application can continue to serve request wityh just 1 pod running. Hope it's more clear now.